# Why `DESCRIBE ?subject ?object` and not just `DESCRIBE ?subject`

Tags: sparql, jena

I have the misfortune of having to maintain some legacy code authored by another programmer; at a certain point the code generates the following SPARQL:

```
DESCRIBE ?subject ?object       
{ 
    SELECT DISTINCT ?subject ?object  
        WHERE { 
             [A where clause which generates unique ?subject ?object pairs]
        } 
        ORDER BY ?subject
}
```

I have a limited understanding of SPARQL, but I can't work out why this would be any different from:

```
DESCRIBE ?subject       
{ 
    SELECT ?subject
        WHERE { 
             [A where clause which generates unique ?subject ?object pairs]
        } 
        ORDER BY ?subject
}
```

i.e.: Why `SELECT DISTINCT` on something which already returns unique pairs, and what difference would `DESCRIBE ?subject ?object` make compared to `DESCRIBE ?subject`.

Both queries return the same result on my data store.

Either I am missing something, or my predecessor made a bit of a mess of this query. Does anyone have any further insights?

Thanks!

Comment: `DESCRIBE ?subject ?object` returns a set of RDF triples that describe all matching resources bound to `?subject` and `?object`.

Comment: SPARQL W3C specs are [online](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#describe)

Comment: If you have something like `:Albert_Einstein :birthPlace :Ulm.` and the `SELECT` query is `SELECT ?subject ?object {?subject :birthPlace ?object}` the `DESCRIBE` query would be `DESCRIBE :Albert_Einstein :Ulm` which returns triples "describing" both, `:Albert_Einstein` and `:Ulm` . Note, `DESCRIBE` is not formally defined in SPARQL. Common result are outgoing (and sometimes incoming)  triples are returned. It totally depends on the triple store

Comment: @AKSW Thanks for the answer. I've found the specs, but the description of the `DESCRIBE` query was a bit vague to me.

Comment: Yes, it is vague as it's not really formally defined. Basically, it returns a set of RDF triples that to some extend (should be) are related to the resources.

Comment: @AKSW Thank you! I understand what's going on now. If you want to move some of your explanation into an answer, I'll accept and upvote. Thanks!

Comment: The DISTINCT makes no difference.  DESCRIBE is vague because allows the server to return what it can (i.e. is configured to). Use CONSTRUCT if the client wants more control of the RDF.